# External Sorting from files in Java

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader

I am wondering how do we write Java code from the following PseudoCode

```
 foreach file F in file directory D
        foreach int I in file F
               sort all I from each file
```

Basically this is part of the [**External Sorting**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting) algorithm, so those files contain lists of sorted integer, and I want to read the first one from each file and sort it and then output to another file, and then move to the next integer from each file again until all the integers are fully sorted.
The problem is that as far as I understand for each file we need a reader, so if we have *N* files then does that mean we need *N* file readers?

======**update**=======

I am wondering is it something that look like this? Correct me if I miss anything or any other better approach.

```
int numOfFiles = 10;
Scanner [] scanners = new Scanner[numOfFiles];
try{
    //reader all the files
    for(int i = 0 ; i < numOfFiles; i++){
        scanners[i] = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader("file"+i+".txt");
    }
}
catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe){

}
```

Comment: `read the first [record] from each file and sort [them,] output to another file, and then move to the next [record] from each file again until all the [records] are fully sorted` won't work: (you may have to *distribute* records to have more than one file to read after a merge *pass*, but more importantly:) as long as you are reading the same sets of records as in the previous pass, nothing will change after the first merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that as far as I understand for each file we need a reader, so if we have N files then does that mean we need N file readers ?

Yes, that's right - unless you want to either have to go back over the data, or the whole of each file into memory. Either of those would let you get away with only one file open at a time - but that may well not suit what you want to do.

Operating systems usually only allow you to open a certain number of files at a time. If you're trying to do something like create a single sorted set of results from a very large number of files, you might want to consider operating on a few of them at a time, producing larger intermediate files. At its simplest, this would just sort two files at a time, e.g.

```
input1 + input2 => tmp-a1
input3 + input4 => tmp-a2
input5 + input6 => tmp-a3
input7 + input8 => tmp-a4

tmp-a1 + tmp-a2 => tmp-b1
tmp-a3 + tmp-a4 => tmp-b2

tmp-b1 + tmp-b2 => result
```

Comment: will the operation be expensive ? is there any other efficient way for solving this ?

Comment: Define "expensive" - and tell us how many files there will be. So long as you don't run over your file handle limit, it shouldn't be too bad. (That will vary by operating system and installation.)

Comment: lets say there are 1000 files, and each file is about 1MB big. by meant 'expensive' I was concerning about accessing 1000 files at the same time during iteration.

Comment: @user1389813: You still haven't really said what sort of cost you're thinking about. The operating system will often buffer reads, which should avoid the disk head moving too inefficiently - and of course on an SSD the considerations are somewhat different anyway. See my edited answer for an alternative approach you could consider.

Comment: I think you just answered my concern. Can you provide the code please.

Comment: @user1389813: No, that wasn't part of the question - and "gimme teh codez" questions aren't very welcome on Stack Overflow. You should attempt to code it yourself, and then if you have a *specific question* you should ask it (as a new question), explaining what you've done so far.

Comment: I have updated my question above along with code fragment, and just want to verify if that's correct or not

Comment: @user1389813: Well, unless you're careful you'll end up leaking file handles in the case of an exception - but apart from that it looks about right.

Comment: Are you talking about like NoSuchElementException while reading the nextInt() ?

Comment: @user1389813: Well *any* exception - including if `FileNotFoundException` is thrown while opening the files. You'll need a `finally` block which closes all the scanners you've opened, understanding that there may be some null array elements.

Comment: I see, so what would you suggest ? like using a list instead of array ?

Comment: @user1389813: I've already said: a `finally` block which cleans up. But now this is a *long* way from your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we must have N file readers for reading N files.

Inorder to iterate all the files in a directory, read the files one by one, and store them in a List. Then sort that list again to get your output.

Answer (score 0):

Just presenting code, not answering "need N file readers ?" :)

use org.apache.commons.io:

```
//get line iterators :
Collection<File> files = FileUtils.listFiles(/* TODO : filter conf */);
List<LineIterator> iters = new ArrayList<LineIterator>();
for(File file : files) {
  iters.add(FileUtils.lineIterator(file, "UTF-8"));
}

//collect a line from each file
List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
for(LineIterator li : iters) {
  numbers.add(li.nextLine());
}

//sort
//Arrays.sort(numbers/*will fail*/);//  :)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a method called Polyphase merge sort I recently learnt in my ds class where you traverse the files in form of runs (a run is a sorted sequence). There are n sources, and a destination.

The gist of this polyphase method is having to keep no file (given a set of files) idle. It significantly reduces the iterations. It's done by taking an fibonacci sequence of an order equal to that of number of files. So in case of 5 files, I'll take the fib sequence of order 5: [1,1,2,4,8], which represent the number of runs you're going to take out of each file and place them, where from files corresponding to runs=1, one of them will be the destination.

In short:

1. Distribute a file into runs according to the fib sequence. [which would mean the entire dataset is in a single file. if that's not the case, you can always create in situ runs where you might want to add dummy runs to suit the sequence]
2. Take first n runs from every file into the buffer, sort them (insertion preferred) and dump them into ONE files. That ONE file is again selected by the fibonacci sequence.
3. Run to a point you get a single file with single run.

This is the paper which neatly explains the polyphase concept. ftp://reports.stanford.edu/pub/cstr/reports/cs/tr/76/543/CS-TR-76-543.pdf

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyphase_merge_sort explains the algo better

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you need N File readers.

```
public void workOnFiles(){

    File []D = new File("directoryName").listFiles(); //D.length should equal to N.

    for(File F:D){

        doSortingForEachFile(F);//do sorting part here. The same reader cannot open same file here again.

    }
}

public void doSortingForEachFile(File f){
    try{
        ArrayList<Integer> list=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Scanner s=new Scanner(f);
        while(s.hasNextInt()){//store ints inside the file.
            list.add(s.nextInt());
        }
        s.close();//once closed, cannot open again.
        Collections.sort(list);//this method will sort the ArrayList of int.
        //...write numbers inside list to another file...
    }catch(Exception e){}
}
```

Comment: Can I ask questions here again?

Comment: I'm not sure why this has been upvoted, as it doesn't answer the question at all: "I want to read the first one from each file and sort it, and then move to the next integer from each file" - your code doesn't do that, nor does it answer the question about what's required *to* do that.

Comment: @User7829300192 You have received a link explaining your question ban. It clearly states the ban is automatic. Nobody can lift if for you at all. Not even a moderator. This is not a manual thing. Keep working on your reputation and the ban might eventually be automatically lifted. But nobody can or will tell you when exactly this will happen.